2 BMS in parallel? To increase peak amp handling in a 2S2P 18650 battery pack
I would like to build a 2S2P 18650 battery pack to power a strobe light. The inrush current when charging the strobe capacitor is quite high. I haven't measured it yet, but it'll be quite high.
Originally this device used nickel metal hydride batteries, which would have some current limiting built-in, I guess. But I would like to use 18650s as they are available and the form factor it's perfectly in this space.
I have on hand a 2S BMS as pictured below with a 15 amp peak current rating. In rush current would only be for a second, and there would be at minimum a few seconds and normally minutes or longer between flashes.   I want to put two of them in parallel to increase that capacity.
Is there any reason I can't do that? Can I simply solder together the B+ and the B- the P+ and the P- and both BM pads so that they're sharing a load?  
Or is there some electrical engineering trickery that I'm missing? If so, do explain it's good to get some information out there for the last person to read.

You can buy inexpensive ICL’ from major disti’s to limit the current to any level and it won’t use more energy just slower charging. 2S2P is ok. 1 or 2 chargers is your choice.

"Inrush Current Limiter"

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/inrush-current-limiters-icl/151

I don't know what the peak flash current is from battery in order to size it. But you can put them in parallel  e.g. https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/ametherm/SL22-0R712/749871
